# Dynamically use varying cell values as WHERE criteria for query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How would one write a query, I'm thinking a **WINDOW** function, to use two parameters (ex. User ID and Date) as *dynamic* inputs for another query?

For example, if you had the following three (3) rows of data. We'll call this **TABLE1**:

```
| USER ID | DATE       |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 2017-04-26 |
| 2       | 2017-04-25 |
| 3       | 2017-04-25 |
```

How would one write a query to grab a data point such as *Total Revenue* for each User ID, but **only** where revenue was collected **on or after** each date value associated to each User ID?

To build on this example, if we had the following separate table. We'll cal this **TABLE2**:

```
| USER ID | REVENUE | REVENUE COLLECTION DATE |
|---------|---------|-------------------------|
| 1       | $1      | 2017-04-26              |
| 1       | $1      | 2017-04-20              |
| 2       | $1      | 2017-04-25              |
| 2       | $1      | 2017-04-26              |
| 3       | $1      | 2017-04-01              |
```

The output I'm chasing would only **SUM** revenues WHERE **TABLE2**.*revenue_collection_date* >= **TABLE1**.*date*

```
| USER ID | TOTAL REVENUE |
|---------|---------------|
| 1       | $1            |
| 2       | $2            |
| 3       | $0            |
```

Again, the output of User ID and Total Revenue is **only** selecting Revenue values where collection date was **on or after** the date in our first table

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

SQL Server:

```
SELECT u.UserID, COALESCE(t.TotalRevenue, 0) AS TotalRevenue
FROM Users AS u
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(r.Revenue) AS TotalRevenue
    FROM Revenue AS r
    WHERE r.UserID = u.UserID
        AND r.CollectionDate >= u.Date
) AS t
```

PostGres:

```
SELECT u.UserID, COALESCE(t.TotalRevenue, 0) AS TotalRevenue
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(
    SELECT SUM(r.Revenue) AS TotalRevenue
    FROM Revenue AS r
    WHERE r.UserID = u.UserID
        AND r.CollectionDate >= u.Date
) AS t ON TRUE;
```

Against your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserID INT,
    Date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE Revenue
(
    UserID INT,
    Revenue DECIMAL(18,2),
    CollectionDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO Users
VALUES
(1, '20170426'),
(2, '20170425'),
(3, '20170425');

INSERT INTO Revenue
VALUES
(1, 1, '20170426'),
(1, 1, '20170420'),
(2, 1, '20170425'),
(2, 1, '20170426'),
(3, 1, '20170401');
```

Returns your expected results

Here's the [PostgreSQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb474/6)

Comment: Thank you for the awesome response! The only hiccup, and possibly this is due to my editing of the question, is that Amazon Redshift apparently doesn't support **LEFT JOIN LATERAL**. So, I think I may have solved it via a simple LEFT JOIN:  `SELECT
  Users.UserID
, COALESCE(SUM(Revenue.revenue),0)
FROM Users
  LEFT JOIN Revenue
    ON Users.UserID = Revenue.UserID
    AND Revenue.collectiondate >= Users.date
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
`